# MS-DOS D-Fend Reloaded file encoding "application/octet-stream; charset=binary" to ASCII in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, encoding, binary, dos, file-type

I have an MS-DOS developed application in [D-Fend Reloaded](https://dfendreloaded.sourceforge.io/) and its DB is stored into a `DATABASE01.DAT` file. I tried to determine the file type through [file](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/file-command-in-linux-with-examples/) command in ubuntu terminal and I get:

```bash
DATABASE01.DAT: application/octet-stream; charset=binary
```

I tried a simple:

```bash
cat DATABASE01.DAT | tr -d '\0' | head -1
```

And I get some data:

```
AAA                     362887637       �   �       FEDERES                            ATTIVI 309                                 FAUSH                  �6Cat
```

The problem is that some fields appears as `�` and I cannot find out which field separator it outputs (looks like a 14 length spaces)

I if run `hexdump -C DATABASE01.DAT`:

```
00000000  50 49 45 52 49 4e 49 20  49 4f 4c 45 20 20 20 20  |AAA    |
00000010  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  |                |
00000020  20 39 34 30 31 34 32 36  31 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  | 362887637       |
00000030  06 00 02 00 7b 07 14 00  08 00 ca 07 07 00 09 00  |....{...........|
00000040  ca 07 20 20 20 20 20 20  20 50 45 52 55 47 49 41  |..       FEDERES|
00000050  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  |                |
```

How can I convert it to a plain text file?

Comment: Use `strings DTABASE01.DAT`. You can also download the source from sourceforge.net.

Comment: Please share (a part of) `hexdump -C DATABASE01.DAT`.

Comment: @JosefZ thank for your answer. I edited the question adding `hexdump -C`

Comment: `dat` is a generic file type. You should check documentation (if it exists) on exact which format it is used. We see a lot of texts, but also `06 00 02 00 7b 07` which smell to include not just text, but also binary data (maybe integers of floating points). In past size was more important than a standardized format